# Safari MacOS - Same image source is getting loaded twice for different image tags

Tags: html, reactjs, cross-browser, browser-cache

I have a grid of speakers in an event's website. Each grid item contains a picture and name of the speaker. Whenever a speaker is clicked on, a dialog opens up with more info about them without reloading the page. This dialog features the same picture as before, same `src` attribute.

In Chrome the dialog opens just fine with the image already loaded, but in Safari the image is loaded again causing an uncomfortable stutter.

The website was built using React and the dialog content is created dynamically.

Is this expected for Safari?
If not, what could be wrong?

> Browser: **Safari 11.0.2 (12604.4.7.1.4)**
>
> System: **macOS 10.12.6 (16G1036)**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello @Razär, Have you find any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: seems like Safari really is the new Internet Explorer